# Active Records-To Check column contains same values in each field

Tags: codeigniter, select, activerecord

In my CodeIgniter application I have a table named as **ims_orderdetails** which contains the different fields but concerned fields in particular case are **o_id** represents *order id* and **status** which may containing **In progress or completed.**
All I want is to check whether status column of ims_orderdetails have all the values marked as completed.
So far I have this piece of code in my model but not working properly.

```
$this->db->from('ims_orderdetails');
$this->db->select('count( distinct status)');
$this->db->where('o_id',$data); 
$result = $this->db->get();
```

**image: ims_orderdetails**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->from('ims_orderdetails');
$this->db->where('o_id',$data); 
$this->db->where('status',1);  // 1 = completed, 0 = In progress 
$result = $this->db->get();

$this->db->from('ims_orderdetails');
$this->db->where('o_id',$data); 
$result2 = $this->db->get();

if ($result->num_rows() == $result2->num_rows())
   return true;
else 
   return false;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer . but when I use your code like this.$this->db->from('ims_orderdetails');
$this->db->select('count( distinct status)');
$this->db->where('o_id',$data); 
$this->db->where('status','completed');  // 1 = completed, 0 = In progress 
$result = $this->db->get();
if ( $result->num_rows() == 1) 
    echo "true"; // all the values marked as completed
else
    echo "false";
 
 echo $result->num_rows();

Comment: its giving true in both cases I have duplicated the record and my order details table contains 2 rows with o_id 46 both rows have status completed it gives true and if i change status to "in progress'. it stills gives true1

Comment: remove 
$this->db->select('count( distinct status)');

Comment: i think by removing this it will just return num of rows where status = "completed" if found. but will not check the existence of any value other than "completed"

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer it works for me.

```
$this->db->from('ims_orderdetails');
$this->db->select('count(*)');
$this->db->where('o_id',$data); 
$this->db->not_like('status', 'completed'); 
$result = $this->db->get();
$res = $result->row_array();
if($res['count(*)']==0){
// do something
}
```